# Is wide sense stationary iff second order stationary?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Wide sense stationary (WSS) process is defined by covariance function being independent of time $E[X(t)X(t+\tau)] = g(\tau)$ and mean is a constant $E[X(t)]=\mu$ where $\mu$ is a constant and $g()$ is a finite valued function.

A second order stationary process is defined by $F_{X(t)}=F_{X(t+\tau)}$ for every $t$ and $\tau$, and $F_{X(t_1),X(t_2)}=F_{X(t_1+\tau),X(t_2+\tau)}$ for every $t_1$, $t_2$ and $\tau$, where $F$ is the distribution.

If we assume finite first and second order moments of the process $X(t)$ is it possible that  wide sense stationary iff second order stationary ?

Comment: What is $F_X(t)$ in your context? There is no random variable $X$ here, only $X(t)$...

Comment: @Did $F_X(t)$ is the distribution of $F_{X(t)}$. I used it as a short hand notation. You are right, that is no $X$.

Comment: Then the first condition reads $F_{X(t)}=F_{X(t+\tau)}$, not what you wrote. To the second condition now: no $X_1$, $X_2$, $X'_1$, $X'_2$ is defined; would you actually mean the condition $F_{X(t_1),X(t_2)}=F_{X(t_1+\tau),X(t_2+\tau)}$?

Comment: @Did That is right. I edited the question.Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Second-order stationarity together with finite variance does imply
wide-sense-stationarity but not the other way around.

Consider the process $\{X(t): -\infty < t < \infty\}$ such that
$X(t) = A \cos(t) + B \sin(t), -\infty < t < \infty$, with $A$ and
$B$ being zero-mean i.i.d. random variable with finite variance $\sigma^2$.
Then,
$$E[X(t)] = E[A\cos (t) + B \sin (t)] = E[A]\cos (t) + E[B] \sin (t) =  0, -\infty < t < \infty$$ and, since $E[AB] = 0$,
$$
E[X(t)X(t+\tau)] = E[A^2]\cos(t)\cos(t+\tau) + E[B^2]\sin(t)\sin(t+\tau) = \sigma^2 \cos(\tau).
$$
Thus, the process is wide-sense-stationary but is 
*not necessarily* second-order stationary, perhaps not even
first-order stationary.  For example,
can you prove that $X(0) = A$ and $X(\pi/4) = (A+B)/\sqrt{2}$ have
the same distribution when, say, $A$ and $B$ are i.i.d $\sim U[-1,1]$ ?

Take a look at [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/488/235)
of mine on dsp.SE too.

Comment: The example is great. I finally got it now. Thank you; +1

Answer (score 0):

In the way you've defined the concepts second order stationarity implies wide stationarity as long as variances exist, but not vice versa.  This is because independence implies zero correlation but not the other way around, unless you know your time series to be jointly normal.